# SQL: CTE query Speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am using SQL Server 2008 and am trying to increase the speed of my query below. The query assigns points to patients based on readmission dates.

Example: A patient is seen on 1/2, 1/5, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9, 2/4. I want to first group visits within 3 days of each other. 1/2-5 are grouped, 1/7-9 are grouped. 1/5 is NOT grouped with 1/7 because 1/5's actual visit date is 1/2. 1/7 would receive 3 points because it is a readmit from 1/2. 2/4 would also receive 3 points because it is a readmit from 1/7. When the dates are grouped the first date is the actual visit date.

Most articles suggest limiting the data set or adding indexes to increase speed. I have limited the amount of rows to about 15,000 and added a index. When running the query with 45 test visit dates/ 3 test patients, the query takes 1.5 min to run. With my actual data set it takes > 8 hrs. 
How can I get this query to run < 1 hr? Is there a better way to write my query? Does my Index look correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example expected results below query.

```
;CREATE TABLE RiskReadmits(MRN INT, VisitDate DATE, Category VARCHAR(15))
;CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Risk_Readmits_Index ON RiskReadmits(VisitDate)

;INSERT RiskReadmits(MRN,VisitDate,CATEGORY)
VALUES
(1, '1/2/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '1/5/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '1/7/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '1/8/2016','Inpatient'), 
(1, '1/9/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '2/4/2016','Inpatient'), 
(1, '6/2/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '6/3/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '6/5/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '6/6/2016','Inpatient'), 
(1, '6/8/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '7/1/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '8/1/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '8/4/2016','Inpatient'),  
(1, '8/15/2016','Inpatient'), 
(1, '8/18/2016','Inpatient'), 
(1, '8/28/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '10/12/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '10/15/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '11/17/2016','Inpatient'),
(1, '12/20/2016','Inpatient')

;WITH a AS (
    SELECT
          z1.VisitDate
        , z1.MRN
        , (SELECT MIN(VisitDate) FROM  RiskReadmits WHERE VisitDate > DATEADD(day, 3, z1.VisitDate)) AS NextDay
    FROM
        RiskReadmits z1 
    WHERE
        CATEGORY = 'Inpatient'
), a1 AS ( 
    SELECT
          MRN
        , MIN(VisitDate) AS VisitDate
        , MIN(NextDay) AS NextDay
    FROM
        a
    GROUP BY
        MRN
), b AS (
    SELECT
          VisitDate
        , MRN
        , NextDay
        , 1 AS OrderRow
    FROM
        a1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          a.VisitDate
        , a.MRN
        , a.NextDay
        , b.OrderRow +1 AS OrderRow
    FROM
        a
        JOIN b
        ON a.VisitDate = b.NextDay
), c AS (
SELECT
    MRN,
    VisitDate
    , (SELECT MAX(VisitDate) FROM b WHERE b1.VisitDate > VisitDate AND b.MRN = b1.MRN) AS PreviousVisitDate 
FROM
    b b1
)
SELECT distinct
    c1.MRN,
    c1.VisitDate
    , CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day,c1.PreviousVisitDate,c1.VisitDate) < 30 THEN PreviousVisitDate
        ELSE NULL
     END AS ReAdmissionFrom
    , CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day,c1.PreviousVisitDate,c1.VisitDate) < 30 THEN 3
        ELSE 0
    END AS Points
FROM
    c c1
ORDER BY c1.MRN
```

Expected Results:

```
MRN VisitDate   ReAdmissionFrom Points
1   2016-01-02  NULL            0
1   2016-01-07  2016-01-02      3
1   2016-02-04  2016-01-07      3
1   2016-06-02  NULL            0
1   2016-06-06  2016-06-02      3
1   2016-07-01  2016-06-06      3
1   2016-08-01  NULL            0
1   2016-08-15  2016-08-01      3
1   2016-08-28  2016-08-15      3
1   2016-10-12  NULL            0
1   2016-11-17  NULL            0
1   2016-12-20  NULL            0
```

Comment: You should describe what you are trying to do, including sample data and desired results.

Comment: I also suggest you post this to the codereview.stackexchange.com site

Comment: I went ahead and posted my expected results.

Comment: What happens if there are visits on 1st, 3rd and 4th?  You treat that as a visit on the 1st, ignore the visits on the 3rd, and then have a readmission on the 4th.  But why can't it be a visit on the 1st, then a readmission on the 3rd?  If you can robustly confirm the business logic as to why some visits are ignored, there are certainly faster ways to write your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops I changed the names of a few cte's (and the post messed up what was code)

It should be like this:

b AS (
    SELECT
          VisitDate
        , MRN
        , NextDay
        , 1 AS OrderRow
    FROM
        a1

```
UNION ALL

SELECT
      a.VisitDate
    , a.MRN
    , a.NextDay
    , b.OrderRow +1 AS OrderRow
FROM
    a AS a
    JOIN b
    ON a.VisitDate = b.NextDay AND a.MRN = b.MRN
```

)

Comment: Please, just edit your original answer rather than add a new one for a correction.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. It nows runs in < 10 seconds! After testing, I also needed to set RiskReadmits.MRN = Z1.MRN in the subquery in a.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here and say you want to change the b cte to 
have AND a.MRN = b.MRN as a second condition in the second select query like this:

```
, b AS (
    SELECT
          VisitDate
        , MRN
        , NextDay
        , 1 AS OrderRow
    FROM
        firstVisitAndFollowUp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          a.VisitDate
        , a.MRN
        , a.NextDay
        , b.OrderRow +1 AS OrderRow
    FROM
        visitsDistance3daysOrMore AS a
        JOIN b
        ON a.VisitDate = b.NextDay AND a.MRN = b.MRN
)
```